# Почему не всплывает модальное окно?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, плагин, всплывающее-окно

Есть сайт на wordpress и плагин видео плеера, построенный на основе библиотеки Magnific Popup когда на странице выводится в виде шорткода `[sp_html5video]` - все отлично работает
код шорткода:

```
<?php
function sp_html5video_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
..
  // Popup Configuration
  $popup_conf = compact('popup_fix'); 
?>
<div class="wp-html5vp-video-row video-row video-row-clearfix" id="wp-html5vp-<?php echo $unique; ?>">
...
<div class="wp-html5vp-popup-conf"><?php echo json_encode( $popup_conf ); ?></div><!-- end of-popup-conf -->
</div>
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $( '.wp-html5vp-video-row' ).each(function( index ) {

    var popup_id   = $(this).attr('id');
    var popup_conf = $.parseJSON( $(this).find('.wp-html5vp-popup-conf').text());

    if( typeof(popup_id) != 'undefined' ) {
      jQuery('#'+popup_id+ ' .popup-youtube').magnificPopup({                    
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade wp-html5vp-mfp-zoom-in wp-html5vp-popup-main-wrp',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: popup_conf.popup_fix == 'true' ? true : 0,
      });

      jQuery('#'+popup_id+ ' .popup-modal').magnificPopup({                                      
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade wp-html5vp-popup-main-wrp',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: popup_conf.popup_fix == 'true' ? true : 0,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Мне нужно на отдельной странице вывести функционал шорткода, с которым хочу произвести доп действия. Для этого - переношу содержимое функции шорткода в php файл, но модальное окно не срабатывает..
Пишет ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Для такого вывода

```
console.log($(this).find('.wp-html5vp-popup-conf').text());
```

вместо (как должно быть по аналогии с шорткодом)
*{"popup_fix":"false"}*
пишет
*Array*
В чем у меня ошибка и как ее устранить?

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался - у меня почему-то в выводе было

```
echo $popup_conf ;
```

вместо

```
echo json_encode( $popup_conf );
```